# Chromium freezes after resuming from standby (Kubuntu 14.04)

Tags: kernel, kubuntu, suspend, chromium, freeze

Every time my laptop resumes from standby the Chromium browser becomes frozen. Graphically, it means that it leaves an unresponsive black square on the desktop. Sometimes, but not always it would start working only after shutting it down and restarting. Mostly, it would still start without a window.

Google Chrome does not freeze that way which makes me speculate that it has to do something with the new Pepper Flash player. I was searching the web and found reports about freezes upon resuming from standby in other programs. The reports blamed the new linux kernel > 3.10.*. I booted with kernel 3.2.* and Chromium indeed did not freeze.

Any workarounds while waiting for the fix of the kernel?

Comment: You can try installing the Pepper Flash plugin in Chromium (`sudo apt-get install pepperflashplugin-nonfree`), but I should note that it's unlikely that that's the issue.

Comment: I have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the `.config/chromium` folder and seems to have solved the issue.

Comment: If you find you're able to produce this problem again, you might wan to  [report a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Answer (score 1):

for my old laptop it was due to GPU.

I executed following

```
ps -ef | grep chrome |grep -v grep | grep gpu | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```